# How to estimate a copula for time series

Tags: time-series, reference-request, copula

I want to estimate a copula for the innovations of two dependent time series (A and B). I have found no reference with a step by step on how to do this. I have only found summarized papers from which I am not able to get the details.

Would you have a reference for this subject?

[EDIT]

Section 4 of [Nonparametric Estimation Of Copulas For Time Series, by JD Fermanian, O Scaillet](http://www.crest.fr/ckfinder/userfiles/files/Pageperso/fermania/cop_jrisk3b.pdf) is an example.

Page 14 of [Estimating copula densities through wavelets, by Genest, Masiello, Tribouley](https://hal-univ-diderot.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00257425/document) is another example. Here the author states that he estimates the copula "once the effect of time has been filtered out". And then he gets figure 9 c). But I do not understand what the author means with "filtering time out".

Comment: Can you share the summarized papers?

Comment: @Lipton Sure, I added this information as an EDIT

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wish to model the joint distribution of some random vector comprised of those 2 time series, so you are interested in time-varying copulas.

There are many ways of estimating copulas, depending on whether they are parametric, nonparametric, etc. [Patton](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:1957361c-cede-4252-aa2a-b3d59e8653cd/datastreams/ATTACHMENT01) Section 2.3 cites a number of papers and textbooks that discuss different methods, so this should help you in your literature search.